# Multiple Renderer for same Coloumn Extjs

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs3.2, I have requirement where i have to add two logic inside renderer first requirement is show tooltip and second is change date format.I have written following code to acheive this

```
renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) 

    {
     Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d-M-Y  g:i A')
    return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
    }
```

But its not working please help!!!
Thanks

Comment: do you get any error? `Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d-M-Y  g:i A')` wont help you to change the date format.. make use of `Date` class or `Ext.util.Format.date()` method with appropriate variables..

Answer (score 0):

You do not return anything from the renderer. For date:

```
return Ext.Date.format(value, 'd-M-Y g:i A');
```

Re tooltip: Do you need a rich tooltip or quick tip would do? In the case of quick tip you can do it this way:

```
metaData.tdAttr =  'data-qtip="The text to display in quick tip"';
```

If you go for quick tips, do not forget to initialize QuickTipManager.